# chrome.tabs.create creates more than one tab at a time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My code is as follows, every time I execute this code, it always opens multiple tabs and I can guarantee that this part of the code is only called once each time

```
chrome.tabs.create({
                        url: "https://www.google.com",
                        active: true
                    }, function (tab1) {
                        var listener = function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
                            if (tabId === tab1.id && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
                                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                                    target: {tabId: tabId},
                                    world: 'MAIN',
                                    args: [e, t],
                                    func: ope
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);
                    });
```

I haven't found a good solution so far

Comment: It means the code outside the posted code is incorrect e.g. it doesn't set a flag that the tab is already open, which can be a global variable or a value in chrome.storage.session.